# Double “that” clauses in one sentence

Tags: syntactic-analysis

"You invest time, energy, and read goods like money or stuff that you own that you share."
I read an article this morning and got confused with the sentence above.
Which word does each that-clause follow?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: That’s not a well formed sentence.

Comment: There should be a comma between "that you own, that you share." Both are relative clauses modifying "money or stuff". Have a look at the poem "The house that Jack Built": https://wordsforlife.org.uk/activities/house-jack-built/